# Amarok 1.4 script: knowing who's running you

Tags: python, linux, dcop

I've been using Amarok 1.4 for a long time, switching to Bogdan Butnaru's packages when KDE stopped supporting it, and I'm now giving Pana a try.

I realised that a script I wrote in Python for Amarok 1.4 will not immediately run without changes under Pana. But instead of [converting my script](http://pana.bunnies.net/wiki/doku.php?id=edit_amarok_scripts_to_work_with_pana), which basically comes down to replacing "amarok" with "pana" in the paths I use, I'd rather make it compatible with both the original Amarok 1.4 and Pana, so that I could be able to distribute only a single version of that script (and possibly modifying it later if other forks become popular).

So, is there a (Python(ic)) way for my script, running from within the player, to find out which program launched it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

pid = os.getppid()
with open("/proc/%s/cmdline" % pid) as f:
    print f.readline()
```

Assuming you are running Linux. Not sure if you need getppid() or getpid() here.
Not so pythonic maybe.

Comment: Thanks! From within the script however, it seems I had to be careful about null bytes. So, to save others some head scratching: append `.replace('\x00', '')` to `f.readline()`.